# What is the difference between URI.escape and URI.encode in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out a difference between a **`URI.escape`** and **`URI.encode`** in Ruby.

Neither is doing what I want them to, which is to completely encode an URL.

For example I want `http://my.web.com` to be `http%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Eweb%2Ecom`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference.  In Ruby 1.9.3 [`encode` is simply an alias for `escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-encode).

**[Edit]** Note that those methods allow an "unsafe" descriptor of characters to encode:

```ruby
URI.encode('http://my.web.com', /\W/) # => "http%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Eweb%2Ecom"
```

Thanks @muistooshort! =)

Comment: What happens if you feed something non-ASCII into `my_encode`?

Comment: @muistooshort: all kinds of terrible things! =)

Comment: Terrible things that can be avoided using things like `URI.encode(s, /\W/)`. There's no need to end the world just because we don't want to read the fine manual :)

Comment: If someone need not encode dots, use `URI.encode('http://my.web.com', /(?!\.)\W/) # => "http%3A%2F%2Fmy.web.com"`

Answer (score 3):

`CGI.escape` almost does what you want:

```
1.9.3p0 :005 > require 'cgi'
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :006 > CGI.escape 'http://my.web.com'
 => "http%3A%2F%2Fmy.web.com"
```

There's usually no point escaping the dots, though.